# Remove Object Stream Encodings from PDF

Tags: ruby, pdf, encoding

I have a PDF which was encoded using Object Streams. I would like to parse this PDF for further processing with other generated PDFs. Most PDF gems I have used claim Object Streams are not supported.

How have you dealt with parsing object streams?

I am currently using [CombinePDF](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf). When I try to load the PDF, CombinePDF chokes on parsing this PDF.

[image: Cannot parse object streams]

Ideally, I would like to take a PDF which has object streams, remove the object streams, save the PDF as a new PDF file without object streams.

Other gems I've tried, [Origami](https://github.com/gdelugre/origami), [Yomu](https://github.com/Erol/yomu), and PDF Reader, all do a lazy parsing.

I know this is possible because I achieved this using Preview on OS X. I opened the said file with Preview on OS X and "Export to PDF…", the new file did not have object streams. How can I reproduce this action in code?

Comment: I am CombinePDF's author. I can't fully support Object Streams without supporting PDF encryption, which is a huge headache and I don't need it for my use-case... *however*, if you found an issue where CombinePDF doesn't manage to open a file, [please open an issue at GitHub](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf/issues). I'll try to make it work as much as I can, even if it's caused by Object Streams.

Comment: Amazing! I shall do just that. To move forward on this problem, I used [QPDF](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/). Maybe this could help you look into how it could come into CombinePDF if you see a merger with this and your use-case